# How to fetch html attribute using plain javascript---any alternave using javascript for $(rrr).attr('value')

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I need to fetch the attribute value using javascript (not to use jquery).

Using below line: I fetch the html code.

`var rrr = gridViewctl.rows[parseInt(rowindex)].cells[4].innerHTML;`

return Html code appears as below:

```
       <input name="ctlDetails:_ctl3:txtName" id="ctlDetails__ctl3_txteName" style="width: 208px;" type="text" value="value text">
```

Can you share me how to fetch attribute `value` field from above text using plain javascript ?

Note: above html is dynamically retrieved in variable and then I need to fetch value attribute from there.
document.getElementById not work out as need to find attribute on variable holded html and not on document object.
If suppose, jquery then, I could use like `$(rrr).attr('value');`

Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById(..ID..).value`?

Comment: need to apply on particular html only and not on document object so, that not work out.

Comment: Value is an attributeof the HTML element, not its code:  `gridViewctl.rows[parseInt(rowindex)].cells[4].value` (although you may need to look at a child node of this lookup

Comment: updated question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lol;
    function onload() { 
        lol = document.getElementById('lolz').value;
    }
    function kk(){
        alert(lol);
    }
</script>

<body onload="onload();">
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="lolz"/>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="kk();"/>
</body>
```

i hope this example will help out

Comment: no, its not work out as html is not known before. so, 'ID' is not known.

Answer (score 1):

Try this updated code :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Get Attribute Value</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getval() {
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
      var y = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setAttribute("value", x);
      var z = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("value");
      document.getElementById("input_value").innerHTML = z;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input name="ctlDetails:_ctl3:txtName" id="ctlDetails__ctl3_txteName" style="width: 208px;" type="text" value="value text">
  <p id="input_value"></p>
  <button onclick="getval();">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its not work for me.    Because, html is return value from variable on which I need to apply and javascript and find value attribute. If I can use jquery then solution is like $('<input....text  value=""').attr(value) but I can't use jquery as per requirement so I need alternate javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your inputs.

finally, It got resolved as below way:

```
 var rrr = gridViewctl.rows[parseInt(rowindex)].cells[4].innerHTML;

 console.log(gridViewctl.getElementsByTagName("input")[rowindex]).value)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use data-* attribute to pass custom data.
 e.g.

```
<li data-animal="bird">Owl</li>
```

To get value:

```
$( "li" ).data( "animal" );
```

It will be fetch the value "bird"

Comment: I need without jquery and only using javascript.

Comment: through JS:
var article = document.getElementById('yourElemID');
 
article.dataset.animal       : yields the data you want to access

For more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to extract the (default) value attribute out of the HTML string as in this (tested) function example.

```
function valueAtrFrom( html)
{
    var regexp = /value="([^"]*)/; // regular expression
    var a = regexp.exec(html);        // execute on html string and get result array
    var value = a && (a.length > 1) ? a[1] : ""; // 2nd array element or ""
    return value;
}
```

and call it like `var value = valueAtrFrom( rrr)`,  or just write the code in-line. As written the regular expression looks for `value="` and then matches any characters up to the next double quote and stores them. These stored characters are the second entry in the result array returned by `.exec`

Of course you could generalized the function to extract any attribute by adding another parameter (see the compile method in the documentation)

---

Edit. Please check if going to this length is really necessary by seeing if

```
var value = gridViewctl.rows[parseInt(rowindex)].cells[4].firstChild.defaultValue;
```

doesn't produce exactly the same answer.